# Magnetometer code: C++ vs C - iosstream, vectors - error iostream: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, io

Hi I'm not sure why no such file or directory keeps coming up. At the moment I'm trying to use cout and it won't let me but this has happened before when I've tried to use a vector.

My whole code is below, I did get it off github:

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <SparkFunLSM9DS1.h>

LSM9DS1 imu;

// SDO_XM and SDO_G are both pulled high, so our addresses are:
#define LSM9DS1_M   0x1E // Would be 0x1C if SDO_M is LOW
#define LSM9DS1_AG  0x6B // Would be 0x6A if SDO_AG is LOW

//output
#define PRINT_CALCULATED
//#define PRINT_RAW
#define PRINT_SPEED 2500 // 250 ms between prints
static unsigned long lastPrint = 0; // Keep track of print time

#define DECLINATION -0.7 // Declination (degrees) in Cov, UK.

void setup() 
{

  Serial.begin(115200);

  imu.settings.device.commInterface = IMU_MODE_I2C;
  imu.settings.device.mAddress = LSM9DS1_M;
  imu.settings.device.agAddress = LSM9DS1_AG;
  if (!imu.begin())
  {
    Serial.println("Failed to communicate with LSM9DS1.");
    Serial.println("Double-check wiring.");
    Serial.println("Default settings in this sketch will " \
                  "work for an out of the box LSM9DS1 " \
                  "Breakout, but may need to be modified " \
                  "if the board jumpers are.");
    while (1)
      ;
  }
}

void loop()
{
  if ( imu.gyroAvailable() )
  {
    imu.readGyro();
  }
  if ( imu.accelAvailable() )
  {
    imu.readAccel();
  }
  if ( imu.magAvailable() )
  {
    imu.readMag();
  }

  if ((lastPrint + PRINT_SPEED) < millis())
  {
    printGyro();  // Print "G: gx, gy, gz"
    printAccel(); // Print "A: ax, ay, az"
    printMag();   // Print "M: mx, my, mz"
    printAttitude(imu.ax, imu.ay, imu.az, 
                 -imu.my, -imu.mx, imu.mz);
    Serial.println();

    lastPrint = millis(); // Update lastPrint time
  }
}

void printGyro()
{
  Serial.print("G: ");
#ifdef PRINT_CALCULATED
  Serial.print(imu.calcGyro(imu.gx), 2);
  Serial.print(", ");
  Serial.print(imu.calcGyro(imu.gy), 2);
  Serial.print(", ");
  Serial.print(imu.calcGyro(imu.gz), 2);
  Serial.println(" deg/s");
#elif defined PRINT_RAW
  Serial.print(imu.gx);
  Serial.print(", ");
  Serial.print(imu.gy);
  Serial.print(", ");
  Serial.println(imu.gz);
#endif
}

void printAccel()
{  
  Serial.print("A: ");
#ifdef PRINT_CALCULATED
  Serial.print(imu.calcAccel(imu.ax), 2);
  Serial.print(", ");
  Serial.print(imu.calcAccel(imu.ay), 2);
  Serial.print(", ");
  Serial.print(imu.calcAccel(imu.az), 2);
  Serial.println(" g");
#elif defined PRINT_RAW 
  Serial.print(imu.ax);
  Serial.print(", ");
  Serial.print(imu.ay);
  Serial.print(", ");
  Serial.println(imu.az);
#endif

}

void printMag()
{  
  #include <iostream>
  using namespace std;
  int initialxmag;
  cout << "Please enter the initial/cu x value of the magnetometer in G:";
  cin >> initialxmag;

  Serial.print("M: ");
#ifdef PRINT_CALCULATED
  Serial.print(imu.calcMag(imu.mx), 2);
  Serial.print(", ");
  Serial.print(imu.calcMag(imu.my), 2);
  Serial.print(", ");
  Serial.print(imu.calcMag(imu.mz), 2);
  Serial.println(" gauss");
  Serial.print("X magnetometer difference is:");
  int diff;
  diff=initialxmag-imu.calcMag(imu.mx);
  Serial.print(diff);
  if diff>-2;
  Serial.print("The magnet has moved away, between 2cm-4cm away from the magnetometer");
  if diff>2;
  Serial.print("The magnet has moved closer, to between 2cm-4cm away from the magnetometer");

#elif defined PRINT_RAW
  Serial.print(imu.mx);
  Serial.print(", ");
  Serial.print(imu.my);
  Serial.print(", ");
  Serial.println(imu.mz);
#endif
}
void printAttitude(float ax, float ay, float az, float mx, float my, float mz)
{
  float roll = atan2(ay, az);
  float pitch = atan2(-ax, sqrt(ay * ay + az * az));

  float heading;
  if (my == 0)
    heading = (mx < 0) ? PI : 0;
  else
    heading = atan2(mx, my);

  heading -= DECLINATION * PI / 180;

  if (heading > PI) heading -= (2 * PI);
  else if (heading < -PI) heading += (2 * PI);

  // Convert everything from radians to degrees:
  heading *= 180.0 / PI;
  pitch *= 180.0 / PI;
  roll  *= 180.0 / PI;

  Serial.print("Pitch, Roll: ");
  Serial.print(pitch, 2);
  Serial.print(", ");
  Serial.println(roll, 2);
  Serial.print("Heading: "); Serial.println(heading, 2);
}
```

So as far as I'm aware this is c++, I've only really done python before so I could be wrong? Though I've still found conflicting advice here it says on c++ iostream will work on c++ (http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/basic_io/) but then a stackoverflow answer said it only worked in c so I'm confused and not sure what the alternative is so I don't get the "cout is not declared in this scope" error.

This is the section of code I'm trying to make work:

```
  #include <iostream>
  using namespace std;
  int initialxmag;
  cout << "Please enter the initial/cu x value of the magnetometer in G:";
  cin >> initialxmag;
```

Any advice on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Standard headers should not be included inside a function. They’re intended to be included at file scope.

Answer (score 1):

Don't `#include` header files in functions but in the global scope.

Comment: ahh okay! thanks I didn't realise. It still shows up after I've moved it though :(

Comment: "iostream: No such file or directory"? Then your compiler is not set up properly. Please have a look at the manual on how to set the default include directories.